# A Bridge Deal with (4, 3, 3, 3) division of suits

Tags: combinatorics

In a bridge deal, what is the probability that all players have a (4, 3, 3, 3) division of suits?

Configurations of $(4,3,3,3)$ splits for $4$ different individuals can go like:
$$
\{4,3,3,3\}\\
\{3,4,3,3\}\\
\{3,3,4,3\}\\
\{3,3,3,4\}
$$

Therefore, number of configurations is: $4!$

We have four configurations where each configuration is the required split. Number of arrangements with required split:
$$
\left(\frac{13!}{4!3!3!3!}\right)^{4}
$$

We divide by total number of arrangements:
$$
\frac{52!}{(13!)^4}
$$

Final answer would be:
$$
4!\frac{\left(\frac{13!}{4!3!3!3!}\right)^{4}}{\frac{52!}{(13!)^4}}
$$

Is my approach correct?

Comment: It should be $\frac{13!}{4!3!3!3!}.$ One extra $3!$ in the denominator.

Comment: But the basic approach is correct.

Comment: The answer simplifies to $$\frac{(13!)^8}{(4!)^3(3!)^{12}52!}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your answer is correct.

It simplifies as:

$$\frac{(13!)^8}{52!(3!)^{12}(4!)^3}\approx 0.00093,$$ or about a tenth of a percent of the time.